# Selecting nested dictionaries and turning them to a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Selecting nested dictionaries and turning them to a DataFrame in Python

From the nested 'biblio' data below, is there a way of sorting this into a data frame with each key as a column? For example, where 'classifications_cpc' is a column header with the codes as the subsequent values?

```
 {
  "publication_reference": {
    "jurisdiction": "US",
    "doc_number": "10236491",
    "kind": "B2",
    "date": "2019-03-19"
  },
  "application_reference": {
    "jurisdiction": "US",
    "doc_number": "201615053025",
    "kind": "A",
    "date": "2016-02-25"
  },
  "priority_claims": {
    "claims": [
      {
        "jurisdiction": "JP",
        "doc_number": "2015062114",
        "kind": "A",
        "date": "2015-03-25",
        "sequence": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "invention_title": [
    {
      "text": "Lithium ion secondary battery",
      "lang": "en"
    }
  ],
  "parties": {
    "applicants": [
      {
        "residence": "JP",
        "extracted_name": {
          "value": "AUTOMOTIVE ENERGY SUPPLY CORP"
        }
      }
    ],
    "inventors": [
      {
        "residence": "JP",
        "sequence": 1,
        "extracted_name": {
          "value": "SAKAGUCHI SHINICHIRO"
        }
      },
      {
        "residence": "JP",
        "sequence": 2,
        "extracted_name": {
          "value": "KIMURA AIKA"
        }
      },
      {
        "residence": "JP",
        "sequence": 3,
        "extracted_name": {
          "value": "MIZUTA MASATOMO"
        }
      }
    ],
    "agents": [
      {
        "extracted_name": {
          "value": "Troutman Sanders LLP"
        }
      }
    ],
    "owners_all": [
      {
        "recorded_date": "2016-02-25",
        "execution_date": "2016-01-28",
        "extracted_name": {
          "value": "AUTOMOTIVE ENERGY SUPPLY CORPORATION"
        },
        "extracted_address": "10-1, HIRONODAI 2-CHOME, ZAMA-SHI, KANAGAWA, 252-0012",
        "extracted_country": "JP"
      }
    ]
  },
  "classifications_ipcr": {
    "classifications": [
      {
        "symbol": "H01M2/02"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M2/14"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M2/18"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0525"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0585"
      }
    ]
  },
  "classifications_cpc": {
    "classifications": [
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0525"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0525"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/463"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0525"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0585"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M10/0585"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/10"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/116"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/116"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/40"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/40"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/409"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/543"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "H01M50/543"
      },
      {
        "symbol": "Y02E60/10"
      }
    ]
  },
  "references_cited": {
    "citations": [
      {
        "sequence": 1,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2011151307",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2011-06-23"
          },
          "lens_id": "052-557-140-975-892"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 2,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2011287301",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2011-11-24"
          },
          "lens_id": "050-516-769-883-801"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 3,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2014205887",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2014-07-24"
          },
          "lens_id": "041-534-822-806-155"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 4,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2015056492",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2015-02-26"
          },
          "lens_id": "101-776-463-080-028"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 5,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "WO",
            "doc_number": "2013047778",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2013-04-04"
          },
          "lens_id": "135-661-134-273-324"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 1,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2011143183",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2011-06-16"
          },
          "lens_id": "095-161-033-897-779"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 2,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2014349169",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2014-11-27"
          },
          "lens_id": "075-950-005-288-26X"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 3,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "US",
            "doc_number": "2015050542",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2015-02-19"
          },
          "lens_id": "003-582-946-821-435"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 4,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "CN",
            "doc_number": "102124591",
            "kind": "A",
            "date": "2011-07-13"
          },
          "lens_id": "157-805-739-981-807"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 5,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "CN",
            "doc_number": "104106155",
            "kind": "A",
            "date": "2014-10-15"
          },
          "lens_id": "003-865-201-672-551"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 6,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "CN",
            "doc_number": "104205416",
            "kind": "A",
            "date": "2014-12-10"
          },
          "lens_id": "182-508-848-265-100"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 7,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "EP",
            "doc_number": "2747167",
            "kind": "A1",
            "date": "2014-06-25"
          },
          "lens_id": "167-072-626-506-628"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 8,
        "patcit": {
          "document_id": {
            "jurisdiction": "JP",
            "doc_number": "2009277397",
            "kind": "A",
            "date": "2009-11-26"
          },
          "lens_id": "061-699-339-033-165"
        }
      },
      {
        "sequence": 9,
        "nplcit": {
          "text": "Extended European Search Report dated Apr. 14, 2016 issued in corresponding European Patent Application No. 16157356.3."
        }
      }
    ],
    "patent_count": 13,
    "npl_count": 1
  },
  "cited_by": {}
}
```

Any Suggestions or Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want a column for each and every key? or only specific ones? For example, the `cited_by` `key` has no `value` in it.

However, assign the data you provided to a variable names `your_data` and try this code:

```
import pandas as pd
list_for_df =[]
classifications = your_data["classifications_cpc"]
symbol_list = classifications["classifications"]
for symbol in symbol_list:
    list_for_df.append(symbol["symbol"])
df = pd.DataFrame(list_for_df,columns=["classifications_cpc"])
```

The data frame will look like that:

```
classifications_cpc
0   H01M10/0525
1   H01M10/0525
2   H01M50/463
3   H01M10/0525
4   H01M10/0585
5   H01M10/0585
6   H01M50/10
7   H01M50/116
8   H01M50/116
9   H01M50/40
10  H01M50/40
11  H01M50/409
12  H01M50/543
13  H01M50/543
14  Y02E60/10
```

Comment: Hi Sam! Thanks for the help. This works great. I have another question. The data I attached is just one value/row of 50,000 values. Would this code be appropriate to use when iterating over thousands of rows ?

Comment: Hi Ayush,
The code will work for whatever size your data is, but willn’t work for whatever structure. If your data has the same struture as the example your showed, so no worries, it will work.
The main question is still: Do you want a column for each and every key? or only specific ones?
If you don’t understand the data structure of JSON, I would recommend you to read this carefully: https://realpython.com/python-json/
Best regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to approach your requirements. As the column names 'classifications_cpc' or 'parties' or 'classifications_ipcr' are each an array of unequal lengths, it would not make sense to put them together into a single DataFrame. Each resultant row will have unrelated fields grouped together.

What you might be looking for is to **extract values using specific key** in the **nested dictionary** or 'lists of dictionaries' . For example using recursive function to extract values using some key:

```
data = {...nested dictionary or 'lists of dictionaries'...}

def get_vals(nested, key):
    result = []
    if isinstance(nested, list) and nested != []:   #non-empty list
        for lis in nested:
            result.extend(get_vals(lis, key))
    elif isinstance(nested, dict) and nested != {}:   #non-empty dict
        for val in nested.values():
            if isinstance(val, (list, dict)):   #(list or dict) in dict
                result.extend(get_vals(val, key))
        if key in nested.keys():   #key found in dict
            result.append(nested[key])
    return result

get_vals(data, 'value')
```

Output

```
['AUTOMOTIVE ENERGY SUPPLY CORP',
 'SAKAGUCHI SHINICHIRO',
 'KIMURA AIKA',
 'MIZUTA MASATOMO',
 'Troutman Sanders LLP',
 'AUTOMOTIVE ENERGY SUPPLY CORPORATION']
```

Or to look for the key 'classifications', you would get 2 lists from 'classifications_ipcr' and 'classifications_cpc':

```
get_vals(data, 'classifications')

[[{'symbol': 'H01M2/02'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M2/14'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M2/18'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M10/0525'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M10/0585'}],
 [{'symbol': 'H01M10/0525'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M10/0525'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/463'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M10/0525'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M10/0585'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M10/0585'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/10'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/116'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/116'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/40'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/40'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/409'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/543'},
  {'symbol': 'H01M50/543'},
  {'symbol': 'Y02E60/10'}]]
```

Another way is to use built-in function `pd.json_normalize()`, but you have to identify **specific keys linkage** to arrive at the data you desire.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['classifications_cpc']['classifications'])
```

Output df

```
    symbol
0   H01M10/0525
1   H01M10/0525
2   H01M50/463
3   H01M10/0525
4   H01M10/0585
5   H01M10/0585
6   H01M50/10
7   H01M50/116
8   H01M50/116
9   H01M50/40
10  H01M50/40
11  H01M50/409
12  H01M50/543
13  H01M50/543
14  Y02E60/10
```